# Button functionality is not working when clicked for 2nd time in React

Tags: reactjs, button

In component A ,I've a btn with search filters , After clicking btn im sending the selected values from search filters into component B where it is getting data from api and rendering the info by using table.

So the problem im facing is, At 1st time btn click all selected values are passed to component B and also data is rendering but when im clicking the btn for 2nd time after changing search filter values , the btn func is not working. I've also checked in console by displaying logs in component B. Im able to see only 1st call logs but not 2nd call.

Im new to React & also rarely develop front-end. Can anyone tell where am i doing mistake ?

Component A:

```
class Hook extends React.Component<any ,any > {

  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this._onButtonClick = this._onButtonClick.bind(this);
        this.state = {
             showComponent: false,

        };

  };

  _onButtonClick() {
           this.setState({
        showComponent: true,

      });
    }

  render() {
      const {classes} = this.props;
  return (

 <div>

  <Box border={1} className={classes.root} display="flex" >

           <div>
           <Button variant="contained" color="primary"
           onClick={this._onButtonClick}>
                   Search
           </Button>
           </div>

   </Box>


   {this.state.showComponent ?
                           <BComponent a = {this.state.dropdown1value} b = {this.state.dropdown2value} c = {this.state.dropdown3value} d = {this.state.dropdown4value}/>
                              : null }


   </div>

  );
  }
}
```

Component B:

```
class BComponent extends React.Component<any ,any > {

      constructor(props) {
              super(props);
              this.getAPIInfo = this.getAPIInfo.bind(this);
              this.state = {
                result: { allInfo: [] },

                  };
      }

      componentDidMount() {
           this.getAPIInfo(this.props.a,this.props.b,this.props.c,this.props.d).then(Response => {this.setState({result: Response })});
         this.setState({loaderFlag: true});
          }


      async getAPIInfo(a, b, c, d) {

              let res;
                    try {
                        calling API

                      });
                    } catch (error) {

                      console.log("API call error", error);
                    } this.setState({loaderFlag: false});

                    return res;
      }

      render() {
         const {classes} = this.props;

      if(this.state.loaderFlag) {
      return (
      <Loader /> );
      }
     else
      return (
        Rendering API data through material UI table
        );
      }

}

export default withStyles(useStyles)(BComponent)
```

Comment: You need to add more code from you ComponentA code. Like your state your dropDowns and your event handlers.

Comment: this.state.showComponent is set only once and hence after the first click it doesn't work. The component B doesn't rerender.

Comment: I can see, that you put some of your logic to componentDidMount, but this lifecycle method is called only once for component lifecycle, after first render and dom updates.
So, when your props will change, you need to recall your api function and update state again. In react class-components better place for it is componentDidUpdate method. In  components with hooks there is useEffect for it.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the ComponentB should be a dumb/presentation component and Component A should fetch the data and send it over to ComponentB as props.

```
this._onButtonClick
```

should then fetch the data from API and pass it over to componentB for display.